# Docker Compose failed to build - Filesharing has been cancelled - eShopOnContainers

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am having trouble running a sample ASP.NET MVC Core application provided by a template from Microsoft
([eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)).

When I trying to run the project using Visual Studio 2019, the below error is popped.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error DT1001  ERROR: for payment-api  Cannot create container for
>   service payment-api: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled
>   exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   at
>   Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__6.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:line
>   0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__4.MoveNext() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:line
>   47\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.HttpApi\Controllers\FilesharingController.cs:line
>   21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}
>   If the error persists, try restarting Docker
>   Desktop.  docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  384

[image: Erroe_log]

Here is my setup,

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.6.1
- docker desktop version 2.3.03

Does anyone have any idea to fix this?

[UPDATE]

The main error is:

```
Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in
> C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you have not shared the drive your project is on (C:\workspaces?)

You need to update File Sharing configuration in your Docker
In New version there is a new security hardening in 2.2.0.0 which has aggressive defaults.
Add all folders you need and then restart Docker for Windows.

[image]

[UPDATE]

If you are using WSL then according to the documentations

> File sharing : 
> The File sharing tab is only available in Hyper-V mode, because in WSL 2 mode and Windows container mode all files are automatically shared by Windows.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#file-sharing

Thanks to @robby

Comment: What path do I want to share? project root folder?

Comment: Yes, I added the folder of the project I was working in. :-)

Comment: See related documentation at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#file-sharing